# use post install for pod in k8s

Tags: azure, kubernetes

in the docs there is an option of using `postStart` hook, however we have some long script that we want to run, how we can do it ? I mean to provide the script and provide the path to run it ... instead of running it inline ...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mention the path of the script, refer this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521684/how-to-execute-a-sql-script-file-in-a-kubernetes-pod)

```
lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", /opt/poststart.sh ]
```