# Run SQL script to all running pods in my AKS

Tags: sql, postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am having the 10 DB Pods in AKS(Azure Kubernetes). We are doing the initial deployment using the Azure Devops.

Now, I am implementing incremental deployment using Azure DevOps.

Question : I want to run some scripts to all running pods in my AKS.

How can I do?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use hooks explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521684/how-to-execute-a-sql-script-file-in-a-kubernetes-pod

Comment: Hello @nirav and welcome to StackOverflow! Does the above comment answer your question?

Comment: Partially. I want to do using Azure DevOps. Also, I can't stop the container. I want to deploy scripts during container is running.